# Creating a file from a output function

Tags: c++

I am calling the function below by a character 'a', I want to call another function by char 'b' to  make a file after displayEntry(i); I am confused to create a file from display fun(), can anyone please help me out ?

In my assignment it is written as below :

(a) Search a certain last name
(b) Save the search result in a file

Where (a) is done but got stuck with (b)...........

```
    // My code is :
void addBook::searchEntry() {
    char lastname[32];
    cout << "Enter last name : ";
    cin >> lastname;
    for(int i = 0;i < count;++i) {
        if(strcmp(lastname, entries[i].lastName) == 0) {
            cout << "Found ";
            displayEntry(i);
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if you are making a file of output, where is your attempt?  I see no pointers, no fopen, nothing.

Comment: As it stands now your question is not good fit for SO. It's unclear what you are asking, you haven't provided the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Hence the downvotes. Please consult the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask questions around here. Welcome to SO, btw.

Comment: Look at `std::ofstream` for the file also why use a char array and not a `std::string` then you replace the `strcmp` with an `==` comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use fstream to write and read from/to files:

```
#include <fstream> // add this to your inclusion 

// My code is :
void addBook::searchEntry()
{
    ofstream out("example.txt", ios::out);

    char lastname[32];
    cout << "Enter last name : ";
    cin >> lastname;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if(strcmp(lastname, entries[i].lastName) == 0)
        {
            cout << "Found ";
            displayEntry(i);
            out << lastname << endl;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    out.close(); // don't forget to close files after you're done with using them 
}
```